# Mailbox in website

Tags: php, ajax

I have a "Contact us" form in my website with the `mailto:` function. The mail goes to my *yahoo account*. I want to implement a mailbox in my website such that i can receive those mail directly from the admin page and reply or delete them accordingly.

How I can do that?

I already have the template I need an explanation on the functions and dynamic content to be implemented.

[image]

Comment: Hi. its Admin LTE template . I have worked on this and also done same requirement.. Now I am in office .. will give u code in evening .. its a complete work u just need to implement as per ur requirement..

Comment: @RahulDambare have you been able to do the mailbox part. It willl be a great help for me thank you in advance

Comment: currently I can give you a hint only that u just need to show php variable in datatable formats and maintain both sender and receiver id, and session id as user id so it only shows email of that user. create table which include mail id, sender id, receiver id, subject, description. Take sender name form sender id while fetching data..

Comment: yes it will  perfectly work in your template in mail box.. you just need to fetch data from mysql tables and show that data in datatable formats. I have implement same thing on same template ...

Comment: ok got it i am understanding part of it , they are all based on storing n retrieving from the mail table. i will try it in the meantime and cross check with your way of doing until you send me the codes.

Comment: @RahulDambare do revert back

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample of my code .. I have change some variable name here ..

```html
$sql = "SELECT * FROM request where user_id='$user'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$sr=1;
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sender_id=$row["sender_id"];
        $receiver_id=$row["receiver_id"];
        $req=$row['req_id'];
        $stat=$row['status'];
        if($stat==0){
            $status="Pending...";
        }
        elseif ($stat==1) {
             $status="Accepted.";
        }
        elseif ($stat==2) {
            $status="Rejected.";
        }
        $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM usertable1 where id='$sender_id' ";
        $result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
        if ($result1->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
                $username=$row1['user_name'];
                $email=$row1['email'];
            }
        }
        $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM  usertable2 where id='$receiver_id' ";
        $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
        if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
            // output data of each row
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()) {
                $source=$row2['source'];
                $destination=$row2['destination'];
            }
        }
```

you will get an idea from this so you can implement as per your requirement.